# HC-0X Bluetooth Module Difference between Slave & Master

Tags: bluetooth

whats the difference between a Module HC-05 Master and HC-06 Slave? I have a slave module (HC-06) but im not sure whats the purpose of the word "Master" in the HC-05

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slave connects to a master.  A master can be a PC with a Bluetooth radio in it / plugged into USB, or it can be a "master" HC-05 module.

Note the HC-05 can work in either master or slave mode.

Examples of masters are PCs, mobile phones when using bluetooth headsets, etc.

Examples of slaves are bluetooth headsets, phones when connecting to a computer, etc.

Comment: So the master has the capability to find other devices and connect? so if I use the HC-05 there I have to use the pair code and that stuff?

Comment: That is correct.